# How can I show PHP include if min-width=40.063em?

Tags: php, html

I have a script in the header that I'm putting on every page, for easy updating I stuck it in it's own page and added it using php include. I'm using media query break points to change the size of the layout in different screen sizes, and I don't want to include this script on small screens.

I don't think it's necessary to provide an example, it's just a php include file with a script tag, like the following:

```
<script>[script here]</script>
```

I think the solution would be to use PHP to include the file if min-width=40.063em, and for anything under that it wouldn't include it. I'm not very good with PHP, at all, so I've come here to see if anyone would know the best way to go about this and shoot me a small example. Thanks for all who help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP runs on the server. CSS runs on the client. You can't decide what content the server is going to send to the client based on information that only the client knows.

You can serve the content regardless and `display: none` it in your stylesheet when the media query matches.

Comment: The issue I have is that I'm loading a script that renders html from a separate server, so I don't technically have access to the html itself (of course I could inspect element and find the rendered code and create a display none for that in css), but I wanted to know if there were any easier way of doing this. I don't like using too many css tricks. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You did answer the question, if you have any more input I'd love to hear it but I think that's as far as we're going to get with this question haha.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin is correct.
The only option might be to use Ajax or similar to load extra content from the server after the front end is rendered.

Comment: As I said to Quentin, the script is rendering html from a different server, so I don't technically have access to the html itself. I can use some css hacks and make a style for the rendered html but I wanted to know if there were anything a little simpler! Thanks for your answer.